# How to sort lines by sed value?

Tags: linux, bash, sorting, sed

I have multiple urls in a file like this:

```
https://private/report-artifact/dsop-pipeline-artifacts/container-scan-reports/anchore/enterprise/enterprise/0.6.1/2020-02-08T004236.092_2801/enterprise-0.6.1.tar
https://private/report-artifact/dsop-pipeline-artifacts/container-scan-reports/atlassian/bamboo-data-center/bamboo-agent/6.10.4/2019-12-17T185400.126_2118/bambo.tar
...
```

I want to them to be sorted A-Z according to the **last value**, ie:

```
https://private/report-artifact/dsop-pipeline-artifacts/container-scan-reports/atlassian/bamboo-data-center/bamboo-agent/6.10.4/2019-12-17T185400.126_2118/bambo.tar
https://private/report-artifact/dsop-pipeline-artifacts/container-scan-reports/anchore/enterprise/enterprise/0.6.1/2020-02-08T004236.092_2801/enterprise-0.6.1.tar
...
```

I can get the `sed` value of the last parameter with
`sed 's|.*/||'` , which gives me the A-Z pattern I am looking for:

```
bambo.tar
enterprise-0.6.1.tar
```

But not sure how I can "sort" the entire url line like I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Duplicate the filename as an additional field, sort by that field, then remove the extra field.

```
sed 's/[^/]*$/& &/' | sort -k 2 | cut -d' ' -f1
```

Answer (score 3):

Barmar's solution works well unless the files contain whitespace.  You can handle spaces (except newlines) with something like:

```
sed 's@\(.*\)/\(.*\)@\2/\1/\2@' | sort -t/ | sed -e 's@[^/]*/@@'
```

but if the paths contain newlines, then using `sed` will be pretty hopeless.  The above is a bit cleaner with awk:

```
awk '{print $NF,$0}' FS=/ OFS=/ | sort -t/ | sed -e 's@[^/]*/@@'
```